# Creating SQL Table from a Go Struct

Tags: sql, go, postgresql

I have been building an API in Go, which I want to link to a `Postgres` SQL table. I have always used `NoSQL` previously but thought it would be good to try a `SQL` database.

Here are my structs

```
type Activity struct {
    Activity string `json:"activity"`
    Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
}

type Payload  struct {
    UserID   string `json:"userId"`
    Duration int    `json:"duration"`
    Type     string `json:"type"`
    Date     int    `json:"date"`
}
```

Based on the above I thought it would be good to have a table for payload which was made via the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE payload (
    userid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration INT,
    type TEXT,
    date INT
);
```

and then created the activity table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
    activity TEXT PRIMARY KEY
    SELECT userid, duration, type, date
    FROM payload;
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your columns are marked non-nullable. This is important for data integrity.

`duration` and `date` both seem mis-represented as `int`. You're in PostgreSQL, so read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html and then consider instead

- `interval` for `duration`, and
- `date` for `date`